# Invalid Parameter error while retrieving image from database using memory stream

Tags: c#, database

I am working on a Window Form application in C# using VS2012. I am getting error in the below code:

```
if (dt.Rows[0]["Photo"] != System.DBNull.Value)                     //Retrieve image into PictureBox from database
{
       photo_aray = (byte[])dt.Rows[0]["Photo"];            //where    photo_aray is byte[] photo_aray;
       MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(photo_aray);
       ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
       Pic.Image = Image.FromStream(ms);                //Where Pic is the pictureBox(Error is getting in this line of "Invalid Parameter")
}
```

I used below code to convert image into byte code and save into "Photo" column of database of `image` datatype:

```
if (Pic.Image != null)
{
       ms = new MemoryStream();
       Pic.Image.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
       byte[] photo_aray = new byte[ms.Length];
       ms.Position = 0;
       ms.Read(photo_aray, 0, photo_aray.Length);
}

sqlcommand cmd = new sqlcommand("INSERT into tbData (Photo) VALUES (photo_aray)",con);
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

Please help if anyone knows. Thank You

Comment: Be warned, you're not closing your MemoryStream properly. It would be better if you used a 'using' statement.

Comment: @Kolky can you please tell me which 'using' statement should I use. I'm using 'using System.IO;' statement already.

Comment: Read more about it here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02.aspx All streams in .NET inherit from `IDisposable` and thus require a using statement as it will close any outstanding IO locks it might hold.

Comment: @Kolky Thanks. Please can you share the code using 'using statement' for image retrieval. Please